# Intermittent failures connecting to 127.0.0.1, no failures when connecting to IP (eth0)

Tags: java, linux, tcp, network-programming, ip

I have a servlet based application running on tomcat(7.0.53), oracle jvm (1.7.x) and CentOS(6.5).
There is a script that peridically "sainity checks" the application by issuing `GET` request to it (every 10sec).

I am encountering the following issue:

When under normal (moderate) load (~4k parallel connections), some of the sanity checks fail with connect timeout (approximately every 10th to 20th request fails).
The connection timeout configured on the client is 120s.
This is happning **ONLY when connecting to `127.0.0.1` (loopback), connecting to `<IP>` of the real lan interface (`eth0`) does not have this issue***.
So:

`curl <args> http://127.0.0.1:<port>` fails,

`curl <args> http://1.2.3.4:<port>` does not fail.

Running `tcpdump` show that the server side does not send back `SYN-ACK` in the failed cases.

Note: Out of curiosity, I disabled IPv6 support (`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`) and the issue dissapeared.
Before, IPv6 is not used, but IPv6 for the loopback (`lo`) interface was initialized and the application was bound to all available interfaces (`127.0.0.1`,  `::1` and `<IP>`).
On the `eth` interface IPv6 was not initialized at all.

What are the possilbe reasons for this kind of behaviour?

Any ideas for furthure troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: If you initialize IPv6 in eth0, do you have the same problem when sending sanity check to eth0?